# Cordova Sqlite plugin inserts entries with null values

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm implementing the [Cordova Sqlite plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) in a Ionic project, so far I've been able to create a database and table and make queries following the functions available through the [ngCordova implementation](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/sqlite.js).

I noticed there's a `insertCollection` function available, which I tried to test, I passed an array to it and even though the inserts are made, the entries are made with null.

This my example table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)
```

I filled an array like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 250000; i++){
  var index = i + 1;
  firstname = firstname + ' ' + index;
  var entry = {
    'firstname' : firstname,
    'lastname' : lastname
  };
  $scope.insertArray.push(entry);
}
```

And then made the insert like this:

```
$cordovaSQLite.insertCollection($rootScope.db, $scope.insertQuery, $scope.insertArray).then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
}, function (err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Where `insertQuery` is the following:

```
INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)
```

I made a select like this:

```
  $scope.select = function() {
    $scope.results = [];
    var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute($rootScope.db, query).then(function(res) {
      if(res.rows.length > 0) {
        console.log('select was successful ' + res.rows.length + ' entries');

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.maxItemsToShow; i++){
          $scope.results.push(res.rows.item(i));
        }

      } else {
        console.log("No results found");
      }
    }, function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
```

I try to display the results on a `ion-list` but the values in firstname and lastname are null for all the items.

What is causing this problem?

Comment: In your for Loop to fill the Array, both firstname and lastname are not initialized.

Comment: firstname and lastname are initialized from the view, I debugged and insertArray does have the entries with the dummy data I set, so it's not an initialization problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `insertCollection` expects an array of arrays, not an array of records. The inner array must contain the values to insert in the order that the question marks (as place holders for the values) appear in the sql statement.

So you need to write:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 250000; i++){
  var index = i + 1;
  firstname = firstname + ' ' + index;
  var entry = [firstname, lastname];
  $scope.insertArray.push(entry);
}
```

Comment: This answer did it, honestly I didn't found an example of how to use that function, I had to check the code to even realize this function existed at all, the documentation http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/ doesn't even mentions it.